# Font size in VMWare Fusion on my Mac

Tags: font, vmware

Since I upgraded to Yosemite 10.10.5 (14F1021) on my MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) the font size on my VMware Fusion is minuscule and I cannot figure out how to increase the font size.  Sure would like to fix this without asking my 2 sons to solve another problem!  It sure would impress them if I could fix this myself!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a resolution issue, more than a font size issue. If so, take these steps:

You may have to shut down (not suspend) your VM whilst making these changes.

Open the Virtual Machine Library window (Shift + Command + L)

On the left side of the window, select the VM you want to change the resolution.

At the top of the Library window select "Settings"

Under Settings, choose "Display"

On the bottom half of the Display preference pane, ***uncheck*** "Use full resolution for Retina Display".

If this does not resolve your issue completely, you may need to adjust the display resolution within your VM was well using it's own display preferences.

Comment: Oh, and I'm assuming that you are referring to the font size within a VM. If you are talking about the Fusion application itself, then I am stumped.